# On the definition of k-simplex

Tags: algebraic-topology

Usually, a $k$-simplex is defined as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ spanned by $k+1$ vertices $v_0,\ldots , v_{k}$, that is the set of linear combinations of the vertices with real non negative coefficients whose sum is $1$. I have two questions: is it possible to substitute $\mathbb{R}^n$ with any real vector space? Has that vector space to be necessarily finite dimensional over $\mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing in the definition of simplex stops you from defining a $k$-simplplex in an infinite dimensional vector space, so the answer to your second question is 'no the vector space does not need to be finite-dimensional'.

As for the first question, as long as you are able to form finite linear combinations you can form a simplex, albeit if you find yourself dealing with a vector space without an inner product, you may have a hard time verifying whether or not the $v_0,\ldots,v_k$ are in general position.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have a little remark: why do the inner product is necessary? Suppose there is not an inner product. Can I just say the vertices are in general position if their differences are linearly independent?

Comment: Yes, that holds in any vector space, the problem I see is exactly checking whether or not they are linearly independent without the inner product. But in theory there is no problem.